# Copying QList into another QList

Tags: c++

I'm facing issues while copying a list into another list.

Below is my code snippet.

Declaration

```
void setData(QList<datadetails> &Data);
--------------------------------------------
void MyClass:: setData( QList<datadetails> &Data)
{
     mywindow->m_dataDetails = Data;
}
```

Below is the error

'void MyClass::setData(int &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'ComponentInterface'

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: int is not container, int<datadetails> won't work, do you mean QList<datadetails> ?

Comment: I have even tried with QList, but that was also not working..Can you please let me know know if we have QList as container ( I have edited the code with QList now)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean :

```
void MyClass::setData(Qlist<datadetails>& Data) {
  mywindow->m_dataDetails = Data;
}
```

And from any part of your code:

```
Qlist<datadetails> data;
MyClass mc;
mc.setData(data);
```

Comment: Your code should not compile: you try to call a function that takes a *reference* to a `QList<datadetails>` with a *pointer* to a `QList<datadetails>`. You should drop the `&` in the function call, or change the `Data` parameter to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it helps of you declare your functions correctly:

> void setData(QList &Data);

..should be inside a class declaration. You just declared a global function.